# Looking for specific lower-case script "r" symbol/font

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'm looking for the lowercase script r shown below (used here to denote the rank of a matrix). Does anyone know how to reproduce it?

[image]

Comment: is there a reason that the r in the `\sigma_{r+1}` in line 5 is an ordinary italic r, and doesn't match the script r earlier in the equation?  as outlandish as it may seem, this sample appears to have been created by tex -- the shapes of the sigmas and deltas are a giveaway.  that leaves open the possibility of asking the author where the script r came from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\mathscr{r}` would be a quick way. To find a script *r*, which matches your sample best, have a look at these sources regarding script fonts:

- The section [Calligraphical and Handwritten Fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html) in the LaTeX Font Catalogue. You could choose a font for your script *r* by looking at the font samples.
- [Script fonts for mathematical use available to LaTeX users](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/math/scriptfonts.pdf) is a short font sampler giving an overview.
- [Better script fonts for maths](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-scriptfonts) in the TeX FAQ
- [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) which contains script symbols, for example look at *Table 213: Math Alphabets* and try the commands and packages there if you like.